# What can we do with a player who camps in a table top game?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, mordheim

We have a group of 8 people in our campaign and we usually do 2 table top battles at a time (not enough table space in our area). The game we are currently playing is Mordheim and for those who have not heard of it, just think of Warhammer but with 10-20 models in a crowded city and the goal of the game (mainly) is to get your opponent off the table by removing their models by range weapons or going in close and winning on the die roll. (very quick summary)

We have a player who just camps at his table edge and hides until your close enough where he charges you when he gets a chance (hides to a point where you cannot shoot any of his units via range).

Unfortunately, since the point of the game is to knock out the other opponent, the player who is going up against the camper has to take 7-10 turns to reach the opponent, not able to shoot at them and the opponent just simply skips his turn once hes behind other buildings until hes at charge range.

We have brought up a few points (ex: on turn 7 and the camper does absolutely nothing, the opponent gets free EXP and the game is ended as a draw) however this only agitates the camper stating that this is strategy, part of the game and comes up with excuses why you don't just go out in the middle of the battlefield.

What can we do with this? Should we let him continue to play his "strategy" or come up with concrete house rules that this is not how the game is intended to be played?

Thanks,

Comment: You could always get others to gang up against the person who is camping in order to encourage them to change their style.

Comment: The variation in scenarios is part of the game design.  If you only ever play once scenario and it's always known ahead of time, people will always find degenerate strategies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are already quite a few ways you could deal with this, some based in the rules, and some beyond the rules:

**As long as one of your units can see the hidden unit, it stops being hidden**

From the rulebook (page 11):

> If an enemy moves so that he can see the hidden warrior, the model is no longer hidden and the counter is removed.

It may be worth sacrificing a fast-moving but weak unit to remove the hidden counters from the opponent's units, thus allowing the rest of your warband to use ranged weapons against them, or charge them first.

**Units within a number of inches equal to your initiative are automatically spotted**

From the rulebook (page 11):

> Enemy warriors will always see, hear or otherwise detect hidden foes within their Initiative value in inches. So a warrior whose Initiative value is 3 will automatically spot all hidden enemies within 3"

So even if you can't get into direct line of sight, again sacrificing a unit may reveal some or all of the enemy warband.

If terrain permits, you may also be able to move one of your own units with a high initiative into a position where line of sight cannot be drawn to it, but its initiative reveals some or all of the enemy warband.

**The All-Seeing Eye of Numas allows you to see hidden units**

From the rulebook (page 100):

> The bearer of the All-Seeing Eye can see all models on the table top, even if they are hidden or out of sight.

If you are lucky enough to have one of these, the enemy can never hide from you!

**Arm your troops with spears**

This will make his charge much less useful, since the Strike First ability means you will hit him before he can hit you.

**Use terrain set up to destroy his chances at the edge of the board**

If you are playing the standard rules for terrain placement for most scenarios, you are within your right to place terrain at the edge of the board that is horrible to defend. Then if you manage to win the roll for first set-up, choose the side he has designed with defence in mind and leave him with nothing worth hiding around.

**Play a different scenario**

If you play scenario 3 (wyrdstone hunt), scenario 4 (breakthrough), scenario 5 (street fight), scenario 7 (hidden treasure) or scenario 8 (occupy), there is a very high chance he will lose by using this tactic.

**Meta-game things that may help you**

- Whenever he initiates this tactic declare a temporary alliance with someone (or everyone) else (if playing with more than two of you), and mob him in his nest. There may be some casualties to your alliance, but you should make quick work of this player's warband and teach him in the process that using this tactic is going to make the game less fun for him.
- Teach yourself to measure distances by sight. Your opponent will end up out of cover and ready for shooting/charging if he declares a charge, but falls a half inch too short.
- Talk to the player (as a group, and as nicely as possible) and just explain that while, yes, his preferred tactic is technically legal, it makes the game much less enjoyable to play for the rest of you.
- Use his tactic right back against him. If you just hide at your starting location and keep passing exactly like him, he will quickly realise just how un-fun it is to be on the receiving end of it.
- Create a list of your own scenarios, making sure that many of them either cannot be won by playing defensively (like scenarios 3, 7, & 8), or actively deter defensive or stationary play.
  If none of these things work, then I would suggest trying to play some games when he isn't invited.

Comment: Winterblood is spot on with this. Mordheim is a fantastic game. You could also change up your terrain sets, bring in house rules for random deployment zones or even place a turn-limit on games. Or try using the Random Encounters table to spice things up.

Answer (score 2):

You could take some hints from FPS games, namely games with snipers.  Once a sniper gets into a strong nest, it can be hard to dislodge them since getting to them leaves you exposed and you can't shoot back at them until you're close.

Some games put objectives out into the open.  Since your objective is elimination, why not put some sort of buff/equipment/units in the open for your players to fight over (ala Hunger Games style?).  Or have stationary artillery that are hard to hold, but can punish players if they stay in a certain area.

Answer (score 1):

Houserules are supreme. If a player keeps making the game un-enjoyable for most, and you can't counter-cheese him, create house-rules that counter his tactic specifically.

His strategy is indeed valid, although when everyone is playing for fun, a strategy that negates fun, destroys the whole point of the game. Try to make him see that people will either not want to play the game at all, or won't want to play the game with him with his attitude.